# Inline style reading in .net from a class file

Tags: html, .net, regex

I need to fetch the style from a html element from .net class file.

```html
<img alt="" style="width: 81px; height: 61px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; font-family: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" src=""https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png"" />
```

output should be

> style="width: 81px; height: 61px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; font-family: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; "

it would be better if it is found through regex.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this regex:** `style="[^"]+"`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY3oE6/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style=".*?"` regex.

`.*?` will match any character ungreedily (and thus, will not eat up 'src' attribute).

C# code:

```
 var input = "<img alt=\"\" style=\"width: 81px; height: 61px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; font-family: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;\" src=\"\"https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png\"\" />";
 var MyRegex = new Regex(@"style="".*?""");
 var result = MyRegex.Match(input).Value;
```